# Model Validation using Data Annotations not working on Mac VS.NET

Tags: macos, rest, asp.net-core

I created a new Web API Application on MacOS with VS.NET. I added a model with the following code:

```cs
public class PersonAddRequest {
   [Required]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a Web API Controller like so:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase {
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult Post(PersonAddRequest model) {
      return base.Ok(model);
   }
}
```

When using PostMan I post JSON as so (note firstName is missing):

```
{
   "lastName":"McDonalds"
}
```

When I run this code on a Web API Application created on a Windows OS validation works as expected. However, when I create the project in MacOS validation doesn't work.

When I create the project in Windows OS then open and run it on MacOS, validation works!

So my question, is this a feature that is missing as part of the scaffolding on VS.NET for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank @nelsontruran for helping me explore VS.NET on Mac. I'm actually running a later version of the Mac (10.14.5 Mojave). However, the version had nothing to do with the original problem.

Thru the patients and persistent help of @nelsontruran I recreated the project but instead of using the suggested templates I dug around a little for the correct application (don't trust the suggested applications in VS.NET). Here's the step-by-step instructions on how to create an API that automatically performs model validation:

1. Open VS.NET for Mac
2. Create a new project
3. When prompted to "Choose a template for your new project", select "App" under the ".Net Core" section on the left side pane.
4. On the right side pane, select API

From there you can review [@nelsontruran's example on git](https://github.com/nelsontkq/example-api-model-validation) to see the magic of Model Validation.

I believe I might have been choosing "Web Application" thinking that it would be the same in Mac as it is in Windows.

A simple oversight on my part. I hope this helps someone who was confused and struggling like me.

Thank you again to @nelsontruran!!!

Answer (score 0):

You require the `FromBody` attribute for the body argument:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]PersonAddRequest model) 
    {
        return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

This is required for model validation.

[Here's an example git repo](https://github.com/nelsontkq/example-api-model-validation) using this form of model validation that is confirmed working on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4

Comment: I just tried adding [FromBody] with no success. Keep in mind that is VS.NET on MacOS. VS.NET on a Windows OS Machine works as expected. Validation is handled automatically. There is no need to use ModelState.IsValid when a Project is created on Windows. But if the Project is created on MacOS the code you provided doesn't work.

Comment: I've testing it on Linux, I'll see how it works on mac when I get home and update.

Comment: any luck testing it on mac @nelsontruran?

Comment: @OneClutteredMind I can confirm that the `[FromBody]` was enough for it to work on macos 10.14.4 High Sierra. Can you create a new webapi `dotnet new webapi` and test it again and confirm it's not working? Also what is your `dotnet --version`

Comment: @OneClutteredMind [here's an example](https://github.com/nelsontkq/example-api-model-validation) web application that returns a validation error if FirstName isn't required